# How to install older version of Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I'm on macOS and I had installed cocoapods 1.12.1 via brew. Recently, I updated to cocoapods 1.13.0 because this was a suggestion to fix an issue (which did not work).

Now, I want to go back to cocoapods 1.12.1, as everybody else in my team is using this version and we all need the same version to prevent Podfile inconsistencies when running `pod install`. This is not possible via brew, because it only has a formula for the latest version 1.13.0.

Can anybody explain me how to go install cocoapods 1.12.1 with Ruby 3.1? Ruby 3.1 is installed via brew.

I've tried to install cocoapods via `gem install cocoapods -v 1.12.1` (trying several options like `--user-install` or `-n /usr/local/bin` as well), but everytime I ran into problems like "command pod not found" or "Gemfile not found" when running the `pod` binary installed by `gem`.

Comment: First of all you need to remove your current version by

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

then set the version you need to install by


sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.25.0


And then check the version installed by 

sudo gem which cocoapods / gem which cocoapods